# What is the best way of converting a svg into App Icons for both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, icons

I'm looking for a tool that can generate the different sizes of icons for the iOS and Android apps from a `svg` image.

Google hasn't been really able to provide me with any "one-click" solution.
Are there any tools out there which are less well known? or perhaps some simple batch scripts that achieve the same?

Ideally something I could run on my windows 10 machine, but linux would work too.

Comment: About android, did you tried ones builded in android studio (Assets Studio)? You can import directly svg which will be changed to xml file. Also working with PSD files.

Comment: I'm trying to build an app using `Flutter` so haven't looked at that. I figured a simple tool for this purpose would've existed and am actually kinda suprised I haven't been able to find one yet

Comment: I know it is not exactly what you asked but I was using this for pngs and jpgs. https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer . It generates all sizes of pngs. More over based on this: Android vs iOS: mdpi = 1x, xhdpi = 2x, xxhdpi = 3x. You should get what you want.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I believe [tool recommendation is off-topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Might be on topic at SuperUser but you need to research the site a bit. Anyway, if you're open to using command-line, consider [Imagemagick where you can specify DPI](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=11746) so that you don't need to upscale/downscale images.

Comment: @xorinzor Well, see "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above". So even if it's about software tool used by developers, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, ..." are off topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My choice is https://github.com/sterlp/svg2png.
For IOS:

```sh
java -jar svg2png.jar -f app_icon.svg -o yourFolder/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset -c ios_icon.json
```

With ios_icon.json like that:

```json
{
  "files": [
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-20x20@1x",
      "height": 20,
      "width": 20
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-20x20@2x",
      "height": 40,
      "width": 40
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-20x20@3x",
      "height": 60,
      "width": 60
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-29x29@1x",
      "height": 29,
      "width": 29
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-29x29@2x",
      "height": 58,
      "width": 58
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-29x29@3x",
      "height": 87,
      "width": 87
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-40x40@1x",
      "height": 40,
      "width": 40
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-40x40@2x",
      "height": 80,
      "width": 80
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-40x40@3x",
      "height": 120,
      "width": 120
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-60x60@2x",
      "height": 120,
      "width": 120
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-60x60@3x",
      "height": 180,
      "width": 180
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-76x76@1x",
      "height": 76,
      "width": 76
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-76x76@2x",
      "height": 152,
      "width": 152
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-83.5x83.5@2x",
      "height": 167,
      "width": 167
    },
    {
      "nameSuffix": "-1024x1024@1x",
      "height": 1024,
      "width": 1024
    }
  ]
}
```

Just make sure generated png files match your configuration from AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json. Mine is

```json
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "size" : "20x20",
      "filename" : "app_icon-20x20@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "scale" : "3x",
      "size" : "20x20",
      "filename" : "app_icon-20x20@3x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "size" : "29x29",
      "filename" : "app_icon-29x29@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "scale" : "3x",
      "size" : "29x29",
      "filename" : "app_icon-29x29@3x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "size" : "40x40",
      "filename" : "app_icon-40x40@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "scale" : "3x",
      "size" : "40x40",
      "filename" : "app_icon-40x40@3x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "size" : "60x60",
      "filename" : "app_icon-60x60@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "scale" : "3x",
      "size" : "60x60",
      "filename" : "app_icon-60x60@3x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "scale" : "1x",
      "size" : "20x20",
      "filename" : "app_icon-20x20@1x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "size" : "20x20",
      "filename" : "app_icon-20x20@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "scale" : "1x",
      "size" : "29x29",
      "filename" : "app_icon-29x29@1x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "size" : "29x29",
      "filename" : "app_icon-29x29@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "scale" : "1x",
      "size" : "40x40",
      "filename" : "app_icon-40x40@1x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "size" : "40x40",
      "filename" : "app_icon-40x40@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "scale" : "1x",
      "size" : "76x76",
      "filename" : "app_icon-76x76@1x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "size" : "76x76",
      "filename" : "app_icon-76x76@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "size" : "83.5x83.5",
      "filename" : "app_icon-83.5x83.5@2x.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
      "scale" : "1x",
      "size" : "1024x1024",
      "filename" : "app_icon-1024x1024@1x.png"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "author" : "xcode",
    "version" : 1
  }
}
```

For Android please refer to README on https://github.com/sterlp/svg2png or create your own json config.

Comment: Sure! With pleasure! Please give me some insight in which part there is a feeling of lack of details. It's hard to see it from my point of view.

Answer (score 13):

First convert you SVG to PNG from this link https://svgtopng.com/ once you convert .PNG then use this link https://makeappicon.com/ to create app icon for both android and iOS.

Comment: Converting it to PNG first and resizing it after will cause a decrease in quality, especially noticeable around curves

Comment: This site is less of a hassle; it doesn't make you enter your email: https://appicon.co/

Comment: @xorinzor, very important point. You can still get perfect results though by exporting a very high resolution version (16384x16384) and uploading that to appicon.co

Answer (score 5):

This is quite late already and this is for ANDROID, but you can actually convert an svg file directly in android studio, right click on drawable folder from res folder and select vector asset:

[image: Open vector asset]

Then select local file (SVG, PSD)

[image: Local file SVG or PSD]

You can then select the svg file from the path field and android studio will directly convert the file as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Design tools(Figma, Zeplin...) allows you generate necessary images for iOS, Android